# Memory Leak in suffix tree c++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I used the library streed2006.cpp from [source](http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/). The code has memory leak in deletion of edges. I cleared the number of edges from hashtable using the following code:

```
//throwing away the edges from hashtable
for(int t=0;t<HASH_TABLE_SIZE;t++)
{
    Edges[t].Remove();
    Edges[t].start_node == -1

}
```

valgrind output:

```
3,920 bytes in 245 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 9 of 12
==6301==    at 0x4029F34: operator new(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind   /vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==6301==    by 0x804A683: Edge::SplitEdge(Suffix&) (suffix_tree.cpp:555)
==6301==    by 0x804B02F: AddPrefix(Suffix&, int) (suffix_tree.cpp:753)
```

Please guide me how to delete the edges.

was able to remove the memory leak. Following is the solution:

```
 void AddPrefix( Suffix &active, int last_char_index )
{
 int parent_node;
 int last_parent_node = -1;

for ( ; ; ) {
    Edge edge;
    parent_node = active.origin_node;
    if ( active.Explicit() ) {
        edge = Edge::Find( active.origin_node, T[ last_char_index ] );
        if ( edge.start_node != -1 )
            break;
    } else { //implicit node, a little more complicated
        edge = Edge::Find( active.origin_node, T[ active.first_char_index ] );
        int span = active.last_char_index - active.first_char_index;
        if ( T[ edge.first_char_index + span + 1 ] == T[ last_char_index ] )
            break;
        parent_node = edge.SplitEdge( active );
    }

    Edge *new_edge = new Edge( last_char_index, T.N, parent_node );
    new_edge->Insert();
    //cout << "Created edge to new leaf: " << *new_edge << "\n";
    AddSuffixLink( last_parent_node, parent_node );
    if ( active.origin_node == 0 ) {
        //cout << "Can't follow suffix link, I'm at the root\n";
        active.first_char_index++;
    } else {
    /*
        cout << "Following suffix link from node "
             << active.origin_node
             << " to node "
             << Suffix_Nodes[ active.origin_node ].suffix_node
             << ".\n";
    */
        active.origin_node = Suffix_Nodes[ active.origin_node ].suffix_node;
        //cout << "New prefix : " << active << "\n";
    }
    active.Canonize();
delete(new_edge);
new_edge = NULL;
}
AddSuffixLink( last_parent_node, parent_node );
active.last_char_index++;  //Now the endpoint is the next active point
active.Canonize();
};
```

and

```
int Edge::SplitEdge( Suffix &s )
{
//cout << "Splitting edge: " << *this << "\n";
Remove();
Edge *new_edge =
  new Edge( first_char_index,
            first_char_index + s.last_char_index - s.first_char_index,
            s.origin_node );
new_edge->Insert();
Suffix_Nodes[ new_edge->end_node ].suffix_node = s.origin_node;
first_char_index += s.last_char_index - s.first_char_index + 1;
start_node = new_edge->end_node;
Insert();
//cout << "New edge: " << *new_edge << "\n";
//cout << "Old edge: " << *this << "\n";
delete(new_edge);
//return new_edge->end_node;
return(start_node);
}
```

Comment: Specific question is?

Comment: @leonardo There is memory leak in the program.My analysis shows that it is due to edges not being deleted. So I need some one to tell me how to delete the edges once they are no longer required.

Comment: Did you read the comment block above the function for `Edges::Remove()`?

Comment: @Leonardo yes i did, it doesnt delete edges, just removes it from hashtable. Which i need to do. I suspect that i need to modify ` dump_edges() ` to delete edges. but don't know how to?

Comment: Yeah, there definitely is no `delete` in this code, but there is `new` dynamic allocation being implemented. So, I think you are right. And the solution would be to implement a `delete` for every `new` used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 void AddPrefix( Suffix &active, int last_char_index )
{
 int parent_node;
 int last_parent_node = -1;

for ( ; ; ) {
    Edge edge;
    parent_node = active.origin_node;
    if ( active.Explicit() ) {
        edge = Edge::Find( active.origin_node, T[ last_char_index ] );
        if ( edge.start_node != -1 )
            break;
    } else { //implicit node, a little more complicated
        edge = Edge::Find( active.origin_node, T[ active.first_char_index ] );
        int span = active.last_char_index - active.first_char_index;
        if ( T[ edge.first_char_index + span + 1 ] == T[ last_char_index ] )
            break;
        parent_node = edge.SplitEdge( active );
    }

    Edge *new_edge = new Edge( last_char_index, T.N, parent_node );
    new_edge->Insert();
    //cout << "Created edge to new leaf: " << *new_edge << "\n";
    AddSuffixLink( last_parent_node, parent_node );
    if ( active.origin_node == 0 ) {
        //cout << "Can't follow suffix link, I'm at the root\n";
        active.first_char_index++;
    } else {
    /*
        cout << "Following suffix link from node "
             << active.origin_node
             << " to node "
             << Suffix_Nodes[ active.origin_node ].suffix_node
             << ".\n";
    */
        active.origin_node = Suffix_Nodes[ active.origin_node ].suffix_node;
        //cout << "New prefix : " << active << "\n";
    }
    active.Canonize();
//ADDED THIS DELETE HERE
delete(new_edge);
new_edge = NULL;
}
AddSuffixLink( last_parent_node, parent_node );
active.last_char_index++;  //Now the endpoint is the next active point
active.Canonize();
};
```

and

```
int Edge::SplitEdge( Suffix &s )
{
//cout << "Splitting edge: " << *this << "\n";
Remove();
Edge *new_edge =
  new Edge( first_char_index,
            first_char_index + s.last_char_index - s.first_char_index,
            s.origin_node );
new_edge->Insert();
Suffix_Nodes[ new_edge->end_node ].suffix_node = s.origin_node;
first_char_index += s.last_char_index - s.first_char_index + 1;
start_node = new_edge->end_node;
Insert();
//cout << "New edge: " << *new_edge << "\n";
//cout << "Old edge: " << *this << "\n";
//ADDED THIS DELETE HERE
delete(new_edge);
//return new_edge->end_node;
return(start_node);
}
```